# Can't play media (video) file inside a ISO archive

Tags: 16.04, video, vlc, iso

I have a ISO file , inside the ISO file there are bunch of video files all of them are in mp4 format  . After mounting  the ISO file if I want to play the video file (tried with vlc and default video player) , it doesn't play  . If I want to copy the any video file to somewhere else , it copies the file but the file size is 0 byte .

There is no problem with the ISO file , because I successfully mounted and run the video file in windows OS .

There is no problem with the vlc player for playing mp4  file , I have played other mp4 file with it .

My OS is ubuntu 16.06

Comment: Don't know how you're mounting, maybe mention. If using that `archive mounter` I've no clue as the location isn't 'real' One surefire way is to use gcdemu, it will work fine on all .iso's. For data discs once mounted the location would be /media/username/volume label. If you don't know how to set up gcdemu then maybe I can find you a link or do an answer.. Just tested here, works well with a data .iso & vlc or any video player.

Comment: I guess archive mounter would be ok with a data disk,  after mounting open in file browser & use context menu to open a file in your player..

Comment: @doug , I did this , but no result

Comment: what is your file manager, the archive manager works ok here on data disks thru nautilus, ie shows up in the sidebar.

Comment: yes , take a look at the screenshot http://oi67.tinypic.com/qo98jm.jpg